# Disk Utility Cannot Erase the hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, macos

I just want to erase everything so I can sell this laptop.
My thought was to come to Disk Util and do an erase.
[image]

But when I choose these settings, the operation keeps failing. Some Apple articles were saying make sure you restart and no USB device is connected which is my case too. So I don't know what to do now.  Or if just there is another way I can erase this laptop so I can sell it, that's all I need too.

Note: This is a late 2013 MBP with `Catalina` installed.

[image]

Comment: Are you in recovery mode? Otherwise erasing usually won't work on the drive that contains the OS currently booted.

Comment: @Robert : I hadn't heard of recovery mode. I was just normally inside Mac.  So should I restart and go to "recovery mode" and then do the same process?

Comment: See [What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065)